# Project Structure View Missing Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin Version Options in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

Im having an incompatible version problem in android studio and i was hoping to change the android gradle plugin version and gradle version in the project structure but when i opened it, they were nowhere to be found. I also tried switching from project to android view but still no luck.

I have tried switching from project to android view but still no luck. I also tried going to the build setting to try and find gradle jdk version but its missing as well.